# Pass event from parent component to child component in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, events, angular-dart

I know how to pass an event from child to parent with `StreamController` and `@Output()`, but what if we want to do it the other way around? Also what if our child component is 2 levels down from the parent?

Suppose our template hierarchy looked something like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

If we do something in `<a>`, how do we listen for it in `<c>`?

Answer (score 0):

The counterpart to `@Output` is `@Input` which allows you to pass data down from a parent to a child.

Briefly:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'a-component',
  template: '''
    <div>
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <p>{{description}}</p>
    </div>
  ''',
)
class MyComponent {
  @Input()
  String title;
  
  @Input()
  String description;
}
```

Parent Template:

```
<a-component [title]="'Encyclopedia'" [description]="'Less comprehensive than the internet'"></a-component>
```

You can read more about it here https://angulardart.xyz/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs